# Nuxt 3 [nuxt] instance unavailable error on server side api call with useAsyncData

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

const { data:page_details ,pending ,error } = await useAsyncData(`${route.params.partner}`, () => $fetch(`${config.public.get_node_url}/partner/page/${route.params.partner}`), { pick: ['data'], initialCache: false })

I am trying server side api call for SEO meta and on localhost it is working properly but on server Getting Error: [nuxt] instance unavailable at Fs.

I am trying this after api call

useHead({
title: page_details.name,

Comment: Please complete your question after this line `useHead({ title: page_details.name,`